# Why is $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}$ not subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

My teacher said that $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x\geq 0,y\geq 0\}$ is not subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I don't understand why this is true because

1) $(0,0)\in M$

2) $\forall x,y\in M$ and $\alpha,\beta\in F\rightarrow \alpha x+\beta y\in M$

Comment: Why do you think $2)$ holds? Note that $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ are in $M$ but $(0,0) - (1,0) = (0,-1)$ is not.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, Oh, I forgot that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can take negative values.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $(2)$ fails. For example, $(1,1) \in M$ but $(-1) \cdot (1,1) = (-1,-1) \notin M$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have been forgetting that the coefficients can be negative.  It is closed under linear combinations with positive coefficients, making it a [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone).